# Printing over-sized QGIS map

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.12

In QGIS, how can I output a map

```
84 in. x 72 in. at 300 dpi
```

with QGIS 2.12.3 and Windows 10?

In print composer, I can dimension the canvas and set dpi, but it seems that I cannot add my map at that size (FAR from it!).

Can it be done in print composer? If not in print composer, then how?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, there is an [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/183882/edit) button, just for future correction. I recommend to read the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), I won't take long!

Comment: What do you mean "I cannot add my map at that size"? Do you get an error message? Does nothing happen? Can you add it at a small size and then not make it bigger? What *precisely* goes wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your responses.My query may have been premature. Just coming to grips with geographical scaling vs illustrator/photoshop resizing -- e.g. scaling before adding map tp composer.

Answer (score 4):

The Composer is capable to print a map in that dimensions.

1. `Project -> New Print Composer`
2. Edit on the tab `Composition` your settings (choose **Custom** presets)

[image: composer example]

*I don't really see your problem though.*

Answer (score 3):

I am using 32 Bit QGIS version 2.14

I have not been able to duplicate your issue

Opening a new print composer, creating a custom sized page in inches all went without a hitch.[image: Screen 1]

I then added my map without a problem

[image: Screen 2]

From there, I centered my map:[image: Screen 3]

Then I set an appropriate scale for the area of interest.[image: Screen 4]

I could have created an atlas, and bound the map to a specific layer, but this answered whether or not I could create a layout of that size in the print composer.

You may have to adjust the composition to print on two pages, unless you have an extremely wide printer!

Comment: I'm having the same issue I suspect the original question asker was having. I get a message saying there will be a Memory Overflow...